# How to make  Installer using WCF

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I have one console application.The application calls WCF on server.
The application  runs perfectly in Visual Studio 2008.

error: [image]

[image]

I used  an installer project in Visual Studio.
I make an installer give primary output to the Application.
It cannot connect to WCF on server.

What steps are necessary to make an installer which has an console (Application)exe,
which in turn uses WCF.

My Scope Initialization starts from initScopeInfo.

```
   private void initScopeInfo()
       {
        DBSyncProxy.SqlSyncProviderProxy client = null;            
        ScopeConfigHandler scopeHandler = null;
        try
        {

    //Providing the Config file name('db_config_new.xml') stored in static variable.    
            DBSyncXMLUtil.setXPathDocument(DBSyncConstants.DB_SYNC_CONFIG_FILE_NAME);

            //DBSyncXMLUtil.setXPathDocument(filepath);
            string endpoint = DBSyncXMLUtil.getSystemParameter(DBSyncXMLUtil.getDocumnetRoot(), "ServiceURL");
```

In setXpathDocument

```
     public static void setXPathDocument(string uri)
      {
public static XPathDocument doc = null;

        doc = new XPathDocument(uri);
    }
     public static string getSystemParameter(XPathNavigator docroot, string key)
    {
        string value = null;
        try
        {
            string xpath = DBSyncConstants.XPATH_SYSTEM_PARAMETER;
            xpath += "[@key='" + key + "']";

            Console.WriteLine("DBSyncXMLUtil :: getParameter() :: XPATH =="+xpath);

    Probably  Error on below mentioned line

            XPathNavigator node = getDocumnetRoot(doc).SelectSingleNode(xpath);
            if (node != null)
                value = node.Value;
            else
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid XPATH");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("DBSyncXMLUtil :: getSystemParameter() :: Exception ==" + ex.ToString());
        }
        return value;
    }
```

Comment: You should provide more details -- maybe some sample code related to how you are calling the WCF service? Any error messages?

Comment: Is your Console Application started by another application? In that case it will try to find the WCF client configuration by the name of this application; like WhatEverApp.exe.config instead of YourConsoleApp.exe.config.

Comment: You haven't given anywhere near enough details for anyone to tell you what is wrong. Are you installing the app on a different machine? Are you running it on the same machine as the console app? Have you configured it correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Actually you **cannot directly create an installer project by adding primary output from a WCF service**. You **should host the WCF service inside a windows service** and add the primary output of the windows service to the installer project.

1. create a WCF.
2. create a windows service and host the WCF inside it (call the WCF from windows service).
3. Create a setup project (installer project).
4. Add the primary output of the windows service to the installer project.

see this link to see the hosting details...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733069.aspx

See this blog. It will help you with the implementation of windows service...

http://joefreeman.co.uk/blog/2010/03/creating-a-setup-project-for-a-windows-wcf-service-with-visual-studio/

Comment: It sounds to me like the OP is trying to create an installer for the WCF *client*, not the service.

Comment: I tend to agree with @Anton. I think installer is for console application that makes requests to WCF service.