# Debug an Installer

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, windows-installer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make  Installer using WCF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6516860/how-to-make-installer-using-wcf)

I am having an installer. It is successfully rebuild. After successful rebuild, I am trying to install a .msi file.

I am getting next error:

```
Error 1001. Exception occurred while initializing the installation
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
'file:///c:\WINDOWS\system32\Files\Default' or one of its dependencies. Then system cannot find the file specified.
```

Please also let me few techniques about debugging an installer in .NET

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know, You can't debug it, because an MSI file is not an executable file. It is an installer file, which Windows will automatically pass as an argument to `msiexec` (Windows Installer) - the actual executable doing all the work, and which you don't have the source code for.

What you need to do is log. Use the `/L*` option (more details [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367988%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).
Open a command prompt, navigate to the folder where your MSI file is, and write something like this:

`msiexec /i myInstaller.msi /L* log.txt`